# Union of $3$ Sets Formula Derivation

Tags: probability

How to derive the formula for a union of 3 sets by using the rules for a union of 2 sets?

What I have so far:

\begin{align} P(A\cup B\cup C) &= P((A\cup B)\cup C) \text{ by commutative property}\\
              &= P(A\cup B) + P(C) - P((A\cup B)C) \\
&= P(A) + P(B) - P(AB) + P(C) - P((A\cup B)C)\\
& = \ldots ? \\
&= P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(AB) - P(AC) - P(BC) + P(ABC)
\end{align}

Comment: use \cup for union and \cap for intersection. [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that \begin{align}-P((A \cup B)C)&=-P(AC \cup BC)\\
&=-[P(AC)+P(BC)-P(AC \cap BC)] \\
&=-P(AC)-P(BC)+P(ABC)\end{align}

Comment: What's the name of that property you're using?

Comment: I am applying inclusion-exlusion property principle onthe union of  $AC$ and $BC$. $(A\cup B)C = AC\cup BC$ is the distributive property.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   P(A∪B∪C) 
   &= P((A \cup B) \cup C) \\   
   &= P(A \cup B) + P(C) - P((A \cup B)C)   \\
   &=  P(A) + P(B) - P(AB) + P(C) - P((A \cup B)C)   \\
   &= P(A) + P(B) - P(AB) + P(C) - P(AC \cup BC)   \\
   &= P(A) + P(B) - P(AB) + P(C) - P(AC) - P(BC) + P(ACBC)  \\
   &= P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(AB) - P(AC) - P(BC) + P(ABC)    \\
\end{align}